# ML Model not predicting properly

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, non-linear-regression

I am trying to create an ML model (regression) using various techniques like SMR, Logistic Regression, and others. With all the techniques, I'm not able to get efficiency more than 35%. Here's what I'm doing:

```
X_data = [X_data_distance]
X_data = np.vstack(X_data).astype(np.float64)
X_data = X_data.T
y_data = X_data_orders
#print(X_data.shape)
#print(y_data.shape)
#(10000, 1)
#(10000,)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_data, y_data, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
svr_rbf = SVC(kernel= 'rbf', C= 1.0)
svr_rbf.fit(X_train, y_train)
plt.plot(X_data_distance, svr_rbf.predict(X_data), color= 'red', label= 'RBF model')
```

For the plot, I'm getting the following:
[image]

I have tried various parameter tuning, changing the parameter C, gamma even tried different kernels, but nothing changes the accuracy. Even tried SVR, Logistic regression instead of SVC, but nothing helps. I tried different scaling for training input data like `StandardScalar()` and `scale()`.

I used [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152610/extremly-poor-polynomial-fitting-with-svr-in-sklearn) as a reference

What should I do?

Comment: Seems like the prediction you get could be interpreted as valid...

Comment: Assuming that "efficiency" means error rate, then that seems pretty good for this data.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher, forgive me but I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I'm hoping for more of a bell shaped output like the data points.

Comment: put a link to the dataset you're using please

Comment: @Yahya, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15s_nQ11r-HX8yQhbJnHgD2UQCaC9GNUXVKjuV9VbkQo/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, we usually follow this convention:

1. For little number of features, go with `Logistic Regression`.
2. For a lot of features but not a lot of data, go with `SVM`.
3. For a lot of features and a lot of data, go with `Neural Network`.

*Because your dataset is a 10K cases, it'd be better to use `Logistic Regression` because `SVM` will take forever to finish!.*

---

Nevertheless, because your dataset contains ***a lot*** of classes, there is a chance of classes imbalance in your implementation. Thus I tried to workaround this problem via using the [StratifiedKFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html) instead of `train_test_split` which doesn't guarantee balanced classes in the splits.

Moreover, I used [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) with [StratifiedKFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html) to perform Cross-Validation in order to **tune** the parameters and try all different **optimizers**!

So the full implementation is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, StratifiedKFold, StratifiedShuffleSplit
import numpy as np


def getDataset(path, x_attr, y_attr):
    """
    Extract dataset from CSV file
    :param path: location of csv file
    :param x_attr: list of Features Names
    :param y_attr: Y header name in CSV file
    :return: tuple, (X, Y)
    """
    df = pd.read_csv(path)
    X = X = np.array(df[x_attr]).reshape(len(df), len(x_attr))
    Y = np.array(df[y_attr])
    return X, Y

def stratifiedSplit(X, Y):
    sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
    train_index, test_index = next(sss.split(X, Y))
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    Y_train, Y_test = Y[train_index], Y[test_index]
    return X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test


def run(X_data, Y_data):
    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = stratifiedSplit(X_data, Y_data)
    param_grid = {'C': [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000], 'penalty': ['l1', 'l2'],
                  'solver':['newton-cg', 'lbfgs', 'liblinear', 'sag', 'saga']}
    model = LogisticRegression(random_state=0)
    clf = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid, cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10))
    clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    print(accuracy_score(Y_train, clf.best_estimator_.predict(X_train)))
    print(accuracy_score(Y_test, clf.best_estimator_.predict(X_test)))


X_data, Y_data = getDataset("data - Sheet1.csv", ['distance'], 'orders')

run(X_data, Y_data)
```

---

Despite all the attempts with all different algorithms, the **accuracy** *didn't* exceed **36%**!!.

---

### Why is that?

If you want to make a person recognize/classify another person by their T-shirt color, you cannot say: hey if it's red that means he's John and if it's red it's Peter but if it's red it's Aisling!! He would say "really, what the hack is the difference"?!!.

And that's exactly what is in your dataset!

Simply, run `print(len(np.unique(X_data)))` and `print(len(np.unique(Y_data)))` and you'll find that the numbers are so weird, in a nutshell you have:

```
Number of Cases: 10000 !!
Number of Classes: 118 !!
Number of Unique Inputs (i.e. Features): 66 !!
```

All classes are **sharing** hell a lot of information which make it impressive to have even up to 36% accuracy!

*In other words, you have no informative features which lead to a lack in the uniqueness of each class model!*

---

What to do? 
I believe you are not allowed to remove some classes, so the only two solutions you have are:

1. Either live with this **very valid** result.
2. Or add more informative feature(s).

---

### Update

Having you provided same dataset but with more features (i.e. complete set of features), the situation now is different.

I recommend you do the following:

1. Pre-process your dataset (i.e. prepare it by imputing missing values or deleting rows containing missing values, and converting dates to some unique values (*[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31701991/string-of-text-to-unique-integer-method)*) ...etc).
2. Check what features are most important to the `Orders` Classes, you can achieve that by using of `Forests of Trees` to evaluate the importance of features. [Here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html) is a complete and simple example of how to do that in `Scikit-Learn`.
3. Create a new version of the dataset but this time hold `Orders` as the `Y` response, and the above-found features as the `X` variables.
4. Follow the same `GrdiSearchCV` and `StratifiedKFold` procedure that I showed you in the implementation above.

---

### Hint

As per mentioned by Vivek Kumar in the comment below, `stratify` parameter has been added in `Scikit-learn` update to the [train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) function.

It works by passing the array-like ground truth, so you don't need my workaround in the function `stratifiedSplit(X, Y)` above.

Comment: Hi @Yahya, thanks a lot for the explanation. Here's another link to the dataset. What do you suggest I should I do in this case:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18ViTjfn9yP9vt40vFH9AjdWw9OITFJidCcsveuDk3q4/edit#gid=1209042444

Comment: thanks a lot!! I changed my model and now, with steps, I achieved an accuracy of 80% on predicting the amount spent.

Comment: @SarvagyaGupta Glad I could help :)

Comment: `train_test_split` also has a stratify param along with `test_size`. Is there a special need to use the custom `stratifiedSplit` method here?

Comment: @VivekKumar Yeah you're right and I'm aware of that, it's has been added in the `Scikit-learn` update. However, it threw an exception when I used it, I forgot what it was but when I checked I did not have time to fix it as my main focus was on finding the reason rather than how to implement. I will add it to the answer as a hint.

Comment: Ok. Great. But `stratify` is present in [`train_test_split` since `0.17`](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/whats_new/v0.17.html). So its not a recent one.

Comment: @VivekKumar I did not mean *recently* by *update*. Thanks for your comment anyway.