# Improve performace of Neural Netkork vs SVC

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, svm

I'm training a model for classification with 100 features, 64 labels and 150K observations (train+test). The data is noisy and already preprocessed.
Using SVC I'm reaching pretty good results, enough for the requirements.
The score is 97.8%

The SVC model delivers 7700 support vectors, so the process requirements for real time predict is big.

I'm wondering if a NN could perform similar. I tested several configurations with 1 and 2 layers but the best result is for 1 layer. With my experiments I get 94.8% with a hidden layer with 300 neurons, not enough for the requirements.

Is included the dataset in the code (70MB)
Fitting is around 60' with my i7 8750H, 16GB msi laptop.

Which layer structure could improve that experiment ?.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

local = 'data.csv'
url='https://www.dropbox.com/s/dccj9leppapy9pv/data.csv?dl=1'
print('Loading dataset')
X = pd.read_csv(url).values[:,1:]
train =  X[ X[:,-1] == 1][:,:-1]
test =   X[ X[:,-1] == 0][:,:-1]
X_train, y_train = train[:,:-1], train[:,-1]
X_test,  y_test  = test[:,:-1],  test[:,-1]

now = time.time()
model = SVC(C=2500, gamma=10, kernel='rbf',verbose=True)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
print('elapsed time:', time.time()-now)
score = model.score(X_test,y_test)
print('SVC score:', score)
print(len(model.support_vectors_) ,'support vectors')

now = time.time()
model = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(300,), activation='logistic',solver='adam',verbose=True,tol=1e-10,learning_rate_init=0.1,learning_rate='adaptive')
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
print('elapsed time:', time.time()-now)
score = model.score(X_test,y_test)
print('NN score:', score)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code example but do you mean to train only on 1s and test only on 0s? I would usually use `sklearn.preprocessing.train_test_split` to randomly split my X and y.

Comment: The test train is previously splitted so for easy is selected from the the last column tagged as 1s and 0s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is you misworded your question but I got what your problem is:

Basically you have a very large dataset with high dimensions with the following facts:

```
Number of cases: 150K
Number of Classes: 64
Number of Features: 99
```

**N.B** You have `99` features (not 100) *excluding* the responses/classes column!

**Goal:**

Find best algorithm that gives the highest accuracy and best performance with respect to CPU Load, Memory Load and Time!

**What have been tried:**

`SVM` Algorithm which gave excellent accuracy result but it took hell a lot of time to finish.

**The question:**

What parameters should be tuned *especially* the `hidden_layer_sizes` to achieve a better accuracy than the one you got already `94.8` using `hidden_layer_sizes=(300,)` in `Neural Network`?

---

### Answer

In your question there are many implicit sub-questions that should be answered. In fact you need to do a complete data analysis on your dataset to end up with a good decision; so it's not a simple straightforward case. Nevertheless, let me split the problem into sub-problems and try to tackle them:

**Firstly:**

As I mentioned in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53354060/ml-model-not-predicting-properly/53355867#53355867) there is a rule of thumb to choose the classification algorithm by convention as follows:

1. For little number of features, go with `Logistic Regression`.
2. For a lot of features but not a lot of data, go with `SVM`.
3. For a lot of features and a lot of data, go with `Neural Network`.

With `150K` observations and `99` Features, `SVM` will take forever to finish! Thus we are left with `Logistic Regression` and `Neural Network`.

According to the above-mentioned rule of thumb, `Neural Network` is a better candidate, and indeed it gave you `94.8%` accuracy score which is great result, however, you require literally ***outstanding*** score (>97%)!.

**Secondly:**

For `Artificial Neural Network`, there is no rule of thumb to choose the size of the hidden layers, but rather there are some guidelines; from *Introduction to Neural Networks for Java (second edition) by Jeff Heaton*:

Number of Hidden Layers:

- **0** only capable of representing linear separable functions or decisions.
- **1** can approximate any function that contains a continuous mapping
  from one finite space to another.
- **2** can represent an arbitrary decision boundary to arbitrary accuracy
  with rational activation functions and can approximate any smooth
  mapping to **any accuracy**.

On the other hand, using too few neurons in the hidden layers will result in underfitting, whereas using too many neurons in the hidden layers may result in overfitting, as a rule of thumb:

- The number of hidden neurons should be between the size of the input layer and the size of the output layer.
- The number of hidden neurons should be 2/3 the size of the input layer, plus the size of the output layer.
- The number of hidden neurons should be less than twice the size of the input layer.

But the question is: **How much time will it cost if we try the above-mentioned suggestions?!**

Here you need to use [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) and you will end up with time consumption more than `SVM` itself!!!

---

So as you can see, there's a trade-off between the accuracy and performance. You cannot claim ***outstanding*** and good ***real-time*** performance at the same time for your particular dataset because it's huge and mostly filled with zeros!!

---

### What to Do?

You have the following options:

1.Either stay with your current `SVM` or `ANN` implementation to achieve ***high accuracy*** but ***worst real-time performance***!

2.Or go with [Gaussian Naive Bayes](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html) which gives ***outstanding performance*** (because it's basically for online classification!) but ***worst accuracy*** as follows:

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
import numpy as np

def getDataset(path, x_attr, y_attr, mapping=None):
    """
    Extract dataset from CSV file
    :param path: location of csv file
    :param x_attr: list of Features Names
    :param y_attr: Y header name in CSV file
    :param mapping: dictionary of the classes integers
    :return: tuple, (X, Y)
    """
    df = pd.read_csv(path)
    if mapping is not None:
        df.replace(mapping, inplace=True)
    X = np.array(df[x_attr]).reshape(len(df), len(x_attr))
    Y = np.array(df[y_attr])
    return X, Y

def run(X_data, Y_data):
    sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
    train_index, test_index = next(sss.split(X_data, Y_data))
    X_train, X_test = X_data[train_index], X_data[test_index]
    Y_train, Y_test = Y_data[train_index], Y_data[test_index]
    clf = GaussianNB()
    print("Start Modeling...")
    now = time.time()
    clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    print('Elapsed Time:', time.time() - now)
    print("Finished Modeling...")
    print(clf.score(X_test, Y_test))

X, Y = getDataset("data.csv", [str(x) for x in range(1,98)] + ["99"], "98")
run(X, Y)
```

**Result**

```
Start Modeling...
Elapsed Time: 0.12834382057189941
Finished Modeling...
0.6888808876959838
```

3.Or go in-between and minimize your accuracy expectations a little then you can achieve a moderate performance using `Logistic Regression` as follows:

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
import numpy as np

def getDataset(path, x_attr, y_attr, mapping=None):
    """
    Extract dataset from CSV file
    :param path: location of csv file
    :param x_attr: list of Features Names
    :param y_attr: Y header name in CSV file
    :param mapping: dictionary of the classes integers
    :return: tuple, (X, Y)
    """
    df = pd.read_csv(path)
    if mapping is not None:
        df.replace(mapping, inplace=True)
    X = np.array(df[x_attr]).reshape(len(df), len(x_attr))
    Y = np.array(df[y_attr])
    return X, Y

def run(X_data, Y_data):
    sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
    train_index, test_index = next(sss.split(X_data, Y_data))
    X_train, X_test = X_data[train_index], X_data[test_index]
    Y_train, Y_test = Y_data[train_index], Y_data[test_index]
    clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0, C=10)
    print("Start Modeling...")
    now = time.time()
    clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    print('Elapsed Time:', time.time() - now)
    print("Finished Modeling...")
    print(clf.score(X_test, Y_test))

X, Y = getDataset("data.csv", [str(x) for x in range(1,98)] + ["99"], "98")
run(X, Y)
```

**Result**

```
Start Modeling...
Elapsed Time: 80.22028756141663
Finished Modeling...
0.9141762953749468
```

4.Or you finally can do is check what features are most important to the Classes, you can achieve that by using of `Forests of Trees` to evaluate the importance of features. [Here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html) is a complete and simple example of how to do that in `Scikit-Learn` then create a new version of the dataset but this time include only the most important features. It's also recommended to have sub-sample of your current dataset by deleting the rows/observations that most contain zeros input!

Comment: Thank you very much Yahya. Much to learn! in your extensive response. Just tested with RandomForest getting an 98.1% accuracy... I need to work on it because the model to disk requires 2GB.

Comment: @Guido Glad I could help :) . Just to let you know that I did not consider Random Forest because I know it's a massive load on RAM and CPU among all others. But I am happy you could make it :)