# Pass subset of df to function - Python

Tags: python, pandas, function

I'm manually passing specific values in a pandas `df` to a function. This is fine but I'm hoping to make the process more efficient. Specifically, I first subset all consecutive values in `Item`. I then take the respective values in `Val` and pass them to `func`. This produces the value I need.This is ok for smaller df's but become inefficient for larger datasets.

I'm just hoping to make this process more efficient to applying the values to the original df.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({ 
            'Time' : ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15'],                   
            'Val' : [35,38,31,30,35,31,32,34,36,38,39,30,25,26,27],                   
            'Item' : ['X','X','X','X','X','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','X','X','X','X'],  
                    })

df1 = df.groupby([df['Item'].ne(df['Item'].shift()).cumsum(), 'Item']).size()

X1 = df[0:5]
Y1 = df[5:11]
X2 = df[11:15]

V1 = X1['Val1'].reset_index(drop = True)
V2 = Y1['Val1'].reset_index(drop = True)
V3 = X2['Val1'].reset_index(drop = True)

def func(U, m = 2, r = 0.2):

        def _maxdist(x_i, x_j):
            return max([abs(ua - va) for ua, va in zip(x_i, x_j)])

        def _phi(m):
            x = [[U[j] for j in range(i, i + m - 1 + 1)] for i in range(N - m + 1)]
            C = [len([1 for x_j in x if _maxdist(x_i, x_j) <= r]) / (N - m + 1.0) for x_i in x]
            return (N - m + 1.0)**(-1) * sum(np.log(C))

        N = len(U)

        return abs(_phi(m + 1) - _phi(m))

print(func(V1))
print(func(V2))
print(func(V3))
```

out:

```
0.287682072452
0.223143551314
0.405465108108
```

If I just try to apply the function using `groupby` it returns `KeyError: 0`. The function doesn't work unless I reset the index.

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Item']).apply(func)
```

> KeyError: 0

Intended Output:

```
   Time  Val1 Item   func
0     1    35    X  0.287
1     2    38    X  0.287
2     3    31    X  0.287
3     4    30    X  0.287
4     5    35    X  0.287
5     6    31    Y  0.223
6     7    32    Y  0.223
7     8    34    Y  0.223
8     9    36    Y  0.223
9    10    38    Y  0.223
10   11    39    Y  0.223
11   12    30    X  0.405
12   13    25    X  0.405
13   14    26    X  0.405
14   15    27    X  0.405
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is at `U[j]` in the `_phi` function. Its `j` is the positional index, so you may use `U.iloc[j]` or change it to list and working straight from list. It seems working on list faster than using `iloc`. My fix changes it to list and working on list. The line `x = ...` in `_phi` could also use a few modifications to make it shorter.

**Method 1**:

```
def func(U, m = 2, r = 0.2):

    def _maxdist(x_i, x_j):
        return max([abs(ua - va) for ua, va in zip(x_i, x_j)])

    def _phi(m):
        x = [U.tolist()[i:i + m] for i in range(N - m + 1)] #change at this line
        C = [len([1 for x_j in x if _maxdist(x_i, x_j) <= r]) / (N - m + 1.0) for x_i in x]
        return (N - m + 1.0)**(-1) * sum(np.log(C))

    N = len(U)

    return abs(_phi(m + 1) - _phi(m))
```

Create custom groupID `s` as you did and groupby on `s` and call `transform`

```
s = df['Item'].ne(df['Item'].shift()).cumsum()
df['func'] = df.groupby(s).Val.transform(func)

Out[1090]:
   Time  Val Item      func
0     1   35    X  0.287682
1     2   38    X  0.287682
2     3   31    X  0.287682
3     4   30    X  0.287682
4     5   35    X  0.287682
5     6   31    Y  0.223144
6     7   32    Y  0.223144
7     8   34    Y  0.223144
8     9   36    Y  0.223144
9    10   38    Y  0.223144
10   11   39    Y  0.223144
11   12   30    X  0.405465
12   13   25    X  0.405465
13   14   26    X  0.405465
14   15   27    X  0.405465
```

---

**Method 2**: It is shorter but less readable. Use `as_strided` from `numpy.lib.stride_tricks`

```
def func(U, m = 2, r = 0.2):

    def _phi(m):
        strd = U.to_numpy().strides[0]
        x = as_strided(U.to_numpy(), (N-m+1, m), (strd, strd))
        C = (np.abs(x - x[:,None]).max(-1) <= r).sum(-1) / (N - m + 1.0)    
        return np.sum(np.log(C)) / (N - m + 1.0)

    N = len(U)

    return abs(_phi(m + 1) - _phi(m))
```

You need to import `as_strided` and create groupID and call groupby transform as method 1

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

s = df['Item'].ne(df['Item'].shift()).cumsum()
df['func'] = df.groupby(s).Val.transform(func)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your are using `apply` with `func` as is, but `func` is not prepared to receive the whole slice of the dataframe directly. In this cases, [lambda expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) are useful.

You could do as follows:

```
# Fisrt, convert each item (string) to a unique value (integer) (based on solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31701991/string-of-text-to-unique-integer-method)
df['ItemID'] = df['Item'].apply(lambda s: int.from_bytes(s.encode(), 'little'))

# Get the consecutive items (based on solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26911851/how-to-use-pandas-to-find-consecutive-same-data-in-time-series)
ItemConsecutive = (np.diff(df['ItemID'].values) != 0).astype(int).cumsum()
ItemConsecutive = np.insert(ItemConsecutive, 0, ItemConsecutive[0])
df['ItemConsecutive'] = ItemConsecutive

# Define your custom func (unmodified)
def func(U, m = 2, r = 0.2):
    def _maxdist(x_i, x_j):
        return max([abs(ua - va) for ua, va in zip(x_i, x_j)])
    def _phi(m):
        x = [[U[j] for j in range(i, i + m - 1 + 1)] for i in range(N - m + 1)]
        C = [len([1 for x_j in x if _maxdist(x_i, x_j) <= r]) / (N - m + 1.0) for x_i in x]
        return (N - m + 1.0)**(-1) * sum(np.log(C))
    N = len(U)
    return abs(_phi(m + 1) - _phi(m))

# Get your calculated values with func based on each consecutive item
func_values = df.groupby('ItemConsecutive').apply(lambda x: func(x['Val'].reset_index(drop=True)))
func_values.name = 'func'

# Complete the dataframe with you calculated values
df = df.join(func_values, on='ItemConsecutive')
```

This is the result:

```
   Item Time  Val  ItemID  ItemConsecutive      func
0     X    1   35      88                0  0.287682
1     X    2   38      88                0  0.287682
2     X    3   31      88                0  0.287682
3     X    4   30      88                0  0.287682
4     X    5   35      88                0  0.287682
5     Y    6   31      89                1  0.223144
6     Y    7   32      89                1  0.223144
7     Y    8   34      89                1  0.223144
8     Y    9   36      89                1  0.223144
9     Y   10   38      89                1  0.223144
10    Y   11   39      89                1  0.223144
11    X   12   30      88                2  0.405465
12    X   13   25      88                2  0.405465
13    X   14   26      88                2  0.405465
14    X   15   27      88                2  0.405465
```

BTW, I'm using pandas version 0.23.3

Answer (score 0):

One need to use apply after the groupby:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Item']).apply( lambda x : myfunc(x) )
```

myfunc operates on sub-dataframes which are grouped by 'Item'.