# Convert string (with different chars) to a unique number, and be able to convert unique number to correct string in python3, and use in np array How?

Tags: numpy, python-3.7, bigint

There are many questions answering for 'Convert string to a unique number'. But I also want to be able to convert 'unique number back to mapped string' in python3. So can't use hash functions.
And I need that converted number to be able to store in numpy array.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31702461/18356082), but it is returning very huge int for very big strings. My strings can be 200 lines long. Getting this error: `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long`, when trying to have it in numpy array.

So, is there any way we could get bit shorter numbers for big strings , and be able to map back those strings from the mapped numbers?

Comment: `200 lines long` digits per line? A 32 bit integer can only reach "4294967295", ie, 10 digits. 64 bits can cover 19 digits. Since numpy is using C you are bound by these limits.

Comment: Ya, any other solution u know?

Comment: The things you want all conflict, so I don't know what you really want. Yes, you can convert a string to unique number and back again, but that number will have to be larger than any fixed size type. This is a consequence of information theory, there's no way to reversibly squeeze an arbitrary amount of information into a fixed-size result like a 64-bit numpy int. But then you say you want to store the number into a numpy **array**, but that's not a single number. You can just utf-8 -encode the string into a numpy array of bytes and back again, so is that acceptable?